# Converting GUI from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm trying to convert a form which I currently have in C# to Java, utilising layout managers.  And it's turning out to be a nightmare.

I've tried setting the sizes of the components, however no difference is present. Also, I cannot get the labels and textboxes to move closer to each other.

Comment: Note that, no the whole, java's layout mechanims are *far* superior to the winform versions. (Microsoft learned from that and as a result the WPF layout mechanisms are much closer to java's, but aren't quite as good.)  You just need to get used to it.

Comment: You'll also want to change the look and feel, to `WindowsLookAndFeel`, for a more native look.

Comment: You can try an IDE like Netbeans, which has a nice design view to setup layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of the buttons and text fields, just put then in a Panel that has nothing but that one item in it.  That will prevent the button/textfield from filling the entire space in the layout.

Other than that the only thing it seems you need to do is put a bit of a margin around the whole thing so that your items aren't right up against the edges of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GridBagLayout` instead of `GridLayout`.
`GridLayout` forces all components to be the same size.

See also `javax.swing.Box`, to put the label - text field pairs in one pane.